# Git Auth Error dev.azure.com - But Works on visualstudio.com

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017, team-explorer, git-credential-manager

There is a developer on my team that gets a git authentication error trying to clone any repositories from our Azure DevOps private instance at dev.azure.com/MyCompany. It doesn't matter whether she starts from ADO and uses the "clone in IDE" command, or if she uses the project explorer in Visual Studio itself.

However, in her project explorer in VS, she also sees our ADO instance as mycompany.visualstudio.com and if she clones from there, it works. I know intellectually it's pointing to the same thing but this is the only person on my team with this strange behavior.

Some things we've tried so far:

- compared our git configuration setting to make sure there weren't any major differences (the only thing that stuck out was she had multiple instances for http.sslcainfo with different values - but even after we got her down to one that didn't fix the issue)
- went into Windows Credential Manager and deleted any instance of cached git creds that she had

I'm an organization admin for our ADO instance and I don't see anything sticking out with her account that could account for this. She is on an older version of Visual Studio - 15.7.3 - but she's not the only one on my team on that version and the others are working fine.

Any other suggestions? I appreciate any insight.

Comment: See: https://jessehouwing.net/configure-visual-studio-to-use-a-different-git-credential-manager-for-windows/

Comment: What exact error does she get (also check the Git Output Window)

Answer (score 0):

Please go `Organization Settings => OverView` to check if the `Use the new URL: https://dev.azure.com/xxx/` is enabled. Only when I connect to one organization which disables the setting can I see `xxx.visualstudio.com` in VS Team Explorer.

(If most members in your Org are using new URL format, you can enable it and wait for several minutes before it take effect. Then check if the issue the developer got would go away)

But in my experience, they both should work. So you can also try:

1.Apart from removing `Generic Credentials`, close VS instance and clean related cache in `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.xxx\ComponentModelCache` and `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\xx\Cache`.

2.When org admin is in `https://dev.azure.com/xxx/` instead of `https://xxx.visualstudio.com`, try removing the developer from current organization and re-add her back.

3.Let the developer update VS to latest `15.9.20`. `15.7.3` is too old, newest version has much more fixes than old `15.7.3`.